# SCEV printing in llvm opt

Tags: llvm

I'd like to analyze Scalar Evolution (SCEV) representation of several values in my IR. Can I display SCEV without writing an auxiliary tool? I mean run opt (or other existing tool) on my IR and specify some command line arguments. I overviewed opt command line parameters, but haven't found something suitable.

Answer (score 2):

*Apart from* Dr. @eliben's answer, there are 2 additional options for `opt` that might be useful (although might not be a direct answer to your question).

#### `-analyze`

This invokes the `Pass::print` member function of the `Pass`. e.g.,

```
opt -analyze -scalar-evolution test/Analysis/ScalarEvolution/incorrect-nsw.ll
```

outputs

```
Printing analysis 'Scalar Evolution Analysis' for function 'bad.nsw':
Classifying expressions for: @bad.nsw
  %i = phi i8 [ -1, %entry ], [ %i.inc, %loop ]
  -->  {-1,+,-128}<%loop> U: [127,0) S: [127,0)         Exits: 127
  %counter = phi i8 [ 0, %entry ], [ %counter.inc, %loop ]
  -->  {0,+,1}<%loop> U: [0,2) S: [0,2)         Exits: 1
  %i.inc = add i8 %i, -128
  -->  {127,+,-128}<%loop> U: [-1,-128) S: [-1,-128)            Exits: -1
  %i.sext = sext i8 %i to i16
  -->  {-1,+,128}<nw><%loop> U: [-1,128) S: [-1,128)            Exits: 127
  %counter.inc = add i8 %counter, 1
  -->  {1,+,1}<%loop> U: [1,3) S: [1,3)         Exits: 2
Determining loop execution counts for: @bad.nsw
Loop %loop: backedge-taken count is 1
Loop %loop: max backedge-taken count is 1
```

#### `-debug-pass`

This *"Print PassManager debugging information"*. You can specify `Arguments`/`Structure`/`Executions`/`Details` for different levels of info. This is helpful since `SCEV` depends on other LLVM Passes. e.g.,

```
opt /dev/null -scev-aa -scalar-evolution -disable-output -debug-pass=Arguments
```

outpus:

```
Pass Arguments:  -targetlibinfo -tti -assumption-cache-tracker -no-aa -domtree -loops -scalar-evolution -scev-aa -verify
```

Comment: FYI, since this answer was written the flag has changed. The syntax is now `opt --passes='print<scalar-evolution>'`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only insights you can gain into the workings of SCEV without touching any code is enable statistics (`opt -stats`) - you can see the statistics emitted by SCEV in [the implementation](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ScalarEvolution_8cpp_source.html) (look for the `STATISTIC` macro invocations in global scope).

Otherwise the SCEV class has a `dump` method which may be more in line with what you're looking for. It's super easy to just run SCEV in a command-line tool and invoke `dump` manually. If you start from one of the [samples here](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples) it shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to see a dump.